# Wrong video duration when trying to make screen capture with libav\ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, libav

I am performing screen capture using libav/c++ with the gdbigrab InputFormat and saving the transcoded video with h.264 to an .mp4 container. Despite doing all the necessary conversions from pts/dts frames and packets, the final video has an issue with its duration. When playing the video, it stops a few seconds before the end and rewinds back to the end.

To diagnose the problem, I used FFprobe to examine the recorded video stream and found the following issues:

`ffprobe my_video.mp4 -show_streams`

Provides the following information:

```
time_base=1/12800
start_pts=28096
start_time=2.195000
duration_ts=38945
duration=3.042578
```

Although I tracked the frame and burst timestamps while recording, starting at zero and ending at the expected pts for the number of frames recorded, I tried to set the start and end time of the stream manually. I observed this problem with different time_base and different video durations, do some minor and major fixes that does not affected this issue. Interestingly, the start time always has the same offset, and the expected/specified video duration in the code is close to the sum of the duration of the video stream and its start time. What am I missing?

> UPDATE:

There is the source of problem:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002a69f15b380] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: -1, duration: 27059
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002a69f15b380] Processing st: 0, edit list 1 - media time: 0, duration: 38912
```

which i get by that command `ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -v 9 -loglevel 99 -i sc_test.mp4`

The question is where this edits happend.